# @Async and @Cacheable Caching Non-Null Response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

If I have a method marked as `@Async` as well as `@Cacheable`, will the condition of not caching the result when null work (considering it is returning a `Future`) ?

```
@Async 
@Cacheable(unless = "#result == null")
public ListenableFuture<ContentSet> doSomething(){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [SPR-12967](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12967). Such return types are not supported.